# removing duplicate cols after full_join R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, filter, duplicates

I am trying to full_join multiple df in a function. All is ok but I get a result df with duplicate cols as presented below. Is there a way to fix this within the function?

```r
inputs<-list.files(pattern = "*dtu.tsv$")
inputs<-inputs%>%map(read_tsv)

merge_dtu<-function(input){
  df<-map(input, ~filter(.x, ESid %in% filt_site$ESid))
  df_merge<-df%>%reduce(full_join, by = c("ESid","allele")) # join! 
  write_tsv(df_merge, "out.tsv")
}

merge_dtu(inputs)
```

```
This provides a df (output of merge_dtu(inputs)) like

ID value_A.x value_B.x  value_A.y value_B.y 
id     a       b          a         b
id     c       d           c        d
```

So I wish to drop value_A.y and value_B.y which are the duplicate cols from the full_join.

How can I achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: `%>% select(-ends_with(".y"))`? With this, you might prefer `full_join(..., suffix=c("", ".y"))`.

Comment: Might be worth the effort to remove duplicate columns other than `"ESid","allele"` *before* joining

Comment: Side note: the fact that you have duplicate columns is one thing, but perhaps you should verify the implied assumption here that the values in the `.y` columns are either always-redundant (as in your example) or disposable, you don't care about their values. If both of those are not true, then I would question the correctness of blindly dropping the columns.

Comment: How about including all duplicated columns into the `by` argument?

Comment: %>% select(-ends_with(".y")) worked perfectly ! running on big files right now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(fake_a.x = "a",
             fake_b.x = "b",
             fake_a.y = "a",
             fake_b.y = "b")

df %>%
  select(-ends_with(".y"))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   fake_a.x fake_b.x
#>   <chr>    <chr>   
#> 1 a        b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For this type of task, you can use variations of `tidy-select` https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html as such:

```r
df1 <- merge_dtu(inputs)

df1 <- select(df1, !ends_with("y"))
```

However, I am not sure why you want to join two dataframes, and then drop all the columns that you obtained from one of them. It might be better just to select the first dataframe and not attempt to join it with the rest. Let me know if you have further questions.